# Jaeger UI Service Dependency Tab not working

Tags: jaeger, jaeger-client-go

In the new Jaeger UI 1.5.x, We have a Service Dependency Tab.

I tried to enable it and run it then I got a Rest Error - I found that  piece of code

`export const ANALYTICS_ROOT = prefixUrl('/analytics/');`

which is getting called by an action in this method

`fetchDeepDependencyGraph(query) { console.log(url = ${ANALYTICS_ROOT}v1/dependencies) return getJSON(${ANALYTICS_ROOT}v1/dependencies, { query }); }`

I found that the Go lang backend is not having this rest call - Any body who knows about this rest call..?

I tried to call the Service Dependency from  Jaeger UI. I got an invalid Json error after selecting the service from the Tab

Comment: What backend are you using? Have you setup Spark to populate the dependency data? Please specify and I can provide an answer. Alternately, you can also ask questions on the CNCF Slack in #jaeger!

Comment: We are using Click house and the backend is Golang which comes up with Jaeger itself

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the clarifications on the question. ClickHouse is not supported by the spark generator, which can be found here:

https://github.com/jaegertracing/spark-dependencies

As you can see from the docs and the code, this is only supported today on Cassandra, ElasticSearch, and OpenSearch. There is currently not support for this on a ClickHouse backend. We'd take a contribution, but today there is no one working on that.